# Query to find duplicates in different fields

Tags: mysql

I have searched and everything I found refers to duplicates of the same field on a record.  The database I am using stores computer hardware and among the fields are en0 and en1 which contain ip addresses.  I need to find records with duplicate ips that exist in either field.  For simplicity here is a sample table:

```
id  serial_no           en0           en1
 1    0000001  10.200.5.102  10.200.5.103
 2    0000002  10.200.6.102  10.200.6.103
 3    0000003  10.200.5.110  10.200.5.102
```

I need the query to return records 1 and/or 3.  Getting either duplicate is ok, best would be to return both.

Thanks

Comment: _"en0 and en1"_ - because, why normalize? Anyway you could use a self-join.

Comment: Tank you very much for your snarky remark.  The table is legacy and normalization is not an option. I will work on the self-join.

Comment: _"normalization is not an option"_ - you could do so in a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, serial_no, en0, en1
FROM mytable 
INNER JOIN (SELECT ip
            FROM (
               SELECT id, serial_no, en0 AS ip
               FROM mytable

               UNION 

               SELECT id, serial_no, en1 AS ip
               FROM mytable ) t
            GROUP BY ip
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t
ON t.ip = en0 OR t.ip = en1
```

The above will return *all* records containing duplicate IPs.

[**Fiddle Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c2f7/1)

The following subquery:

```
SELECT ip
FROM (
  SELECT id, serial_no, en0 AS ip
  FROM mytable

  UNION 

  SELECT id, serial_no, en1 AS ip
  FROM mytable ) t
GROUP BY ip
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

is used to return duplicate IPs. Note the use of `UNION` instead `UNION ALL`. This way an IP that is repeated in columns `en0`, `en1` of the *same* record will not be considered as duplicate. Change to `UNION ALL` if you want different behavior.

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic answer and for including the sql fiddle - I did not know it existed.  I have used various code fiddles before but not for sql!  I am getting an "Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row" when I run on my server, which is 5.6.  I did convert the table and field names to the actuals for the real DB and perhaps I messed that up.  I am re-checking and also creating the sample table I used here.  Hopefully I will find that problem.

Comment: So duplicating the fiddle example in the DB worked fine - I'll work out how to apply to the real DB.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @wesmat There is a problem with my query. The `WHERE` clause should normally be like `en0 IN (... subquery here ) OR `en1 IN (...subquery repeated here)`. I tried to do it the other way round in order to make it more succinct, but it doesn't work if the subquery return more than one value.

Comment: @wesmat Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c2f7/1) for an alternative solution using `JOIN`.

Comment: So I found the problem and the fiddle also has it.  If I add another row that is a full duplicate it fails.  I added '0000004',  '10.200.5.102',  '10.200.5.103' to the fiddle and get an error.

Comment: Brilliant! You found the solution while I was still finding the cause.  The JOIN version handles full duplicate records.  You are the best.

Comment: @wesmat OK, I've edited my answer to correctly handle the case of multiple duplicate IPs.